# Pure CSS solution to stacking columns of divs

Tags: html, css

I want to float a sidebar div to the right beside two stacked divs, both floated to the right.

You can find the code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/okcomputer82/ED4WJ/2/

I'm sure I can do this by grouping the left divs, but I would like to know if there is a cleaner way.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you draw a picture of how you'd like it to appear?

Comment: The two stacked DIV's should be floated to the right or left?

Answer (score 2):

remove `"clear: both;"` from css class .left, and it will be ok.

**NEW**
update class .left to "clear:left;"

```
.left {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    background: yellow;
}
```

and put your right div to be at the first place like below

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>

</div>
```

example : http://jsfiddle.net/ED4WJ/5/

Comment: they are stacked, do you mean over leaped

Comment: The OP wants vertical stacking, not side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.content

{   
    Float:left;
    width:960px;
    height:100px;

}

.left
{
float:left;
width:40%;
height:100%;
background-color:red
}

.right
{
  float:left;
   width:20%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:yellow

}
```